# phantomJS and Google Chart getImageURI()

Tags: phantomjs

I would like to get image/png;base64 (server side) of a Google chart with phantomJs

```
$base64 = exec('phantomjs myscript.js');
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo base64_decode( $base64 );
```

myscript.js :

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log( msg );
    phantom.exit();
};
page.open('http://getpngchart.dev/chart.php');
```

chart.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart']});

        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {

            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable( [['Task', 'Quantity'], ['Critical', 35], ['Routine', 6], ['Adjust', 2]] );
            var options = {colors: ['#E34036','#F7A500','#FF0097'], legend: { position: "none" }};

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart( document.getElementById('chart_div') );

            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
                console.log( chart.getImageURI() );
            });

            chart.draw(data, options);

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width:250px; height:250px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I launch chart.php with Chrome I get the expected base64 string

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAgAElEQVR4Xu2dCXwURfbHX889kzshCSHgKuB6gIp4LIgicrgiCyogyCEquq7ihbgerCvoKvtfr9VVBEQ...AiNzE1kBBp19gBWQQAEGXQIjcxNZAQadfYAVkEABBl0CI3MTWQEGnX2AFZBAAQZdAiNzE1mB/wedEj8SPZNwdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

But when I use the terminal (#phantomjs myscript.js), I get a wrong base64 with a lot of AAAA... :

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAewAAAHkCAYAAAD8eRwNAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAIABJREFUeAEAwYI+fQH/////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

My goal is to get the same base64 with Chrome and with phantomJS

Comment: I added the code for chart.php

Comment: Does this issue cause any problems for you? Is the image broken? The image generation is probably done through the canvas and since Chrome and PhantomJS 1.x (which is comparable to Chrome 13) have different engines, this will always be different. So I tried it and I get a largely inflated image. It seems that PhantomJS doesn't compress the image data.

Comment: Possibly related issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12446

Comment: Yes, I tried to put a console.log('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAPoAAAD6CAYAAACI7Fo9AAAgAElEQVR4X...') (with the full string) instead of console.log( chart.getImageURI() ) and get the good string with the terminal, so the problem comes from getImageURI()

Answer (score 0):

This script works fine. But an small tweak on the datastream was needed @line2

```
$base64 = str_replace(' ','+',$base64);
//Remove identifier string from begining of data.
$base64 =  str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $base64);
```